# MSBuild: How to replace csc.exe with my own tool

Tags: c#, msbuild, roslyn

Long story short, I am building an AOP framework (due to some issue with existing IL weaving libs with my DLL). But my goal is to use Roslyn and do the weaving at the syntax tree level.

This means that I am building a new compiler which is intended to work as an in-place replacement for the standard compiler which does the extra AOP work.

I've read some on defining custom toolsets. But the information I found is sparse and its not really clear how/where the msbuild config file changes need to be made.

Is there more concise information on introducing your own toolset or a way which I could substitute the C# compiler directly (since I use CSharpCommandLineParser and I should have the same params as CSC.exe)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the msbuild property (or environment variable) for CscToolPath and CscToolExe.

However, you should be careful to preserve debugging of your transformed code somehow.

Comment: Thanks. Will give it a try. I've seen those mentioned in some pages but since it was older docs I assumed this was the old way for the build to find the tools.